# How would you ,using a heap of lists, find the shortest heap

Tags: java, list, heap

That probably was not the best description for it. My question is using a heap of lists how would you find the shortest out of the multiple heaps and then add the next element to it? Is this easy? I am not looking for the code for it. Really looking for an explanation of if/how it could be done. I just started learning about heaps so any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: This is very unclear. Are you trying to find the shortest list in a heap, or do you have multiple heaps that contain lists?

Comment: Yes, sorry and shortest list in a heap

Comment: Try creating a min heap and use the length of your lists to order the heap. That way, your shortest list will always be at the root of the heap.

Comment: And after you add an item to the list, you have to re-sift the root element, because it might have become longer than the next-longest.